# What Coolant Hose should I buy?

Tags: coolant, land-rover, range-rover

1999 Range Rover 4.6 HSE (P38):

I have a leak in a coolant hose from the reservoir to the throttle body heating plate. Can I use any heater hose with some hose clamps, or does it need to be the exact specific hose from the manufacturer? Also, any idea what size hose this might be?

Here's a link to the heating plate it hooks up to:

[https://www.amazon.com/MGM000010K-Throttle-Heater-Gasket-Discovery/dp/B0096W4VEY/ref=pd_sbs_263_1/140-5141091-4494659?_encoding=UTF8&pd_rd_i=B0096W4VEY&pd_rd_r=3d7971cb-7dfb-47a7-8a91-3e6ddf8912e6&pd_rd_w=3xzpm&pd_rd_wg=gICEM&pf_rd_p=d28ef93e-22cf-4527-b60a-90c984b5663d&pf_rd_r=Y09TVB2R5JTNX26V2SQJ&psc=1&refRID=Y09TVB2R5JTNX26V2SQJ](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0096W4VEY)

Answer (score 0):

"Can I use any heater hose with some hose clamps"

Yes but you may have to use fuel hose, 1/2" is small as heater hose goes. As long as there no kinks after install you can use straight hose.

Comment: 1/2” is a common internal diameter for heater hose.

Comment: Whats your point?